# can we create a java process which can build(gradle build) application?

Tags: java

I've written some code for building apps using Buildprocess API in Java,
like below..

```
public class BuildTest {

public static void main(String[] args)  {

System.out.println("Build Start here...");

String path="C:/Myapp/PORTAL/AppXX";

String cmd="gradle clean dist";
String line="";
try{

 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( cmd.split(",") );
    builder.directory(new File(path));
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = builder.start();
    InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream ();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Out : " + line);
}
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

My goal is: instead of running commands on console gradle clean dist for compiling or build my application, I want to use a Java process which can do same without using console commands.
Is this the right way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Instead of writing that process yourself, I'd recommend to use a build server, such as [TeamCity](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Gradle) or [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) which both have Gradle support.

Comment: thanks @Halmackenreuter.but i am looking for to do the same job (build tool job. & using build tool & api ) from my simple java code.